# XML Formatting into groups

Tags: xml, xslt

Question about XML formatting.
I have an XML like this:

```
    <Transaction>
<AK1>
    <AK101/>
    <AK102/>
</AK1>
<AK2/>
<AK3/>
<AK4/>
<AK3/>
<AK4/>
<AK4/>
<AK3/>
<AK5/>
<AK2/>
<AK3/>
<AK4/>
<AK5/>
<AK2/>
<AK5/>
<AK9/>
    </Transaction>
```

and would like to format like this using XSLT. :

```
    <Transaction>
<AK1>
    <AK101/>
    <AK102/>
</AK1>
<Sets>
    <Set>
        <AK2/>
        <Errors>
            <Error>
               <AK3/>
               <AK4/>
            </Error>
            <Error>
               <AK3/>
               <AK4/>
               <AK4/>
            </Error>
            <Error>
               <AK3/>
            </Error>
        </Errors>
        <AK5/>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <AK2/>
        <Errors>
            <Error>
               <AK3/>
               <AK4/>
            </Error>
        </Errors>
        <AK5/>
    </Set>
    <Set>
        <AK2/>
        <AK5/>
    </Set>
<Sets>
        <AK9/>
```

Anything from AK2 until the next AK2 should be in a separate XML node called

Anything from AK3 to AK4 should be in separate Error elements. There could be 0 or more AK4s for each AK3. There may be 0 or more AK3 elements.

Thank You

Comment: We need to know what technology you are using - what are you using to transform one piece of XML into another. if Java then I suspect it would be pretty easy with DOM, fairly simple with SAX. XSLT may be plausible but I'm so rusty with it that I'm not sure.

Comment: Also a bit more clarity on the requirement - is it always the case that AK2 signals the start of a set, and the first occurence of AK2 signals the start of sets

Comment: Chris, We are just using XSLT transformation to achieve this.

Comment: Ah - I'm not the man to help I'm afraid. Years since I've used XSLT - I'd urge you to mention XSLT in your question and add it as a tag, you're much more likely to get an answer. Good luck

Comment: Yes, AK2 triggers the start of the Set. Regardless of what comes after it, all the elements after AK2 and until the next AK2 should be bundled into a Set, including the sub-elements, if any.

Comment: Do a search - [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) is probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Why is `<AK9/>` excluded from the last `Set`?

Comment: That's not what you said in your question: *"Anything from AK2 until the next AK2 should be in a separate XML node"*.

Comment: Please let me correct my statement. Anything from AK2 until AK5 should be in a <Set>.

Comment: Michael.hor257k, this worked perfectly. There is an addition to the original request. I have updated the Original input and the intended output. AK3 and AK4 elements to be grouped as well into new XML elements called <Errors><Error>. Could you please help this as well? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If - as it seems - you can use XSLT 2.0, you could try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Transaction">
    <!-- first pass: group from AK2 to AK5 -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="AK2">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="AK5">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::AK2">
                        <Set>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </Set>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output: group all sets together -->
    <Transaction>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$first-pass/*" group-adjacent="name()='Set'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <Sets>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </Sets>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Transaction>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8Aw

Comment: Michael.hor257k, this worked perfectly. There is an addition to the original request. I have updated the Original input and the intended output. AK3 and AK4 elements to be grouped as well into new XML elements called <Errors><Error>. Could you please help this as well? Thanks in advance